# How can I insert the rows I received from the API into mysql

Tags: python, mysql, pymysql

how i can insert my table mysql result this code?

```
   response = requests.request("GET", url, headers=headers, data=payload, verify=False)
    user_json = json.loads(response.text)
    
    for i in user_json:
        db_ins = pymysql.connect(host="localhost", user="root", password="password", db="vmremover")
        cursor_insert = db_ins.cursor()
        sql_insert = "INSERT INTO `users` (`id`, `username` ................
        This is while wrong, i know :) how me write correct?
```

```
for i in user_json:
   sql_insert = "INSERT INTO `users` (`id`, `username` ...)
```

this i need help :)

Comment: https://pythontic.com/database/mysql/insert%20rows This should help!

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem you are experiencing is in writing right query so that with every passing loop you can add the desired data to the mysql database. It can be done as follows:

```
sql_insert="INSERT INTO table_name (id, username ...) VALUES (%s, %s, ...)"
sql_insert.execute(sql_insert, (i['id'], i['name']...))
```

In above code, in the second statement the values (i['id'] ...) replace the %s inside the first line of code.
Hence, it should write the intended data into the table for every iteration.

Comment: @Sshoaib-wani for i in user_json:
    print(i['id'], i['mail']) error TypeError: string indices must be integers

Comment: print(user_json['result'][0]['mail'])
print(user_json['result'][1]['mail']) this correct, how i can insert in sql  with while  @Shoaib_wani

Comment: paste full code above then I can help you